# Input not being read properly by if condition statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

one would think this is easy, but for some odd reason, my conditional statement is ignoring user input.

If I input a character 'N' or 'n' it still executes the 'Y' portion of the conditional statement, have a look:

```
while (i < 10) {
        cout << "Would you like "<< nameOfDish[i] << "? Please enter Y or N.\n";
        cin >> userResponse;



        if (userResponse == 'y' || 'Y')
        {
            cout << "How many orders of " << nameOfDish[i] << " would you like?\n";
            cin >> quantityOfDish[i];
            if (quantityOfDish[i] == 0) {
                cout << "I suppose you're entitled to change your mind.\n";
            }
            else if (quantityOfDish[i] < 0) {
                cout << "Your generosity is appreciated but I must decline!\n";
                quantityOfDish[i] = 0;
            }

            i++;
        }

        else if (userResponse == 'n' || 'N')
        {
            i++;
        }

        else
        {
           cout << "I think you mumbled NO, so I'll just go on.\n";
           i++;
        }

    }
```

Is there any particular reason why despite inputting 'n' it still goes into the 'Y' if conditional block?

I have stepped through the code in the debugger, and I noticed that the userResponse variable is being read in properly. Yet, the if condition does not seem to be working properly. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, which book is teaching the syntax `(userResponse == 'n' | 'N')`?  This seems to be a common beginners mistake.

Comment: You can use `tolower()` or `toupper` reduce the number of comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement (and your other if statement) is not doing what you think it does:

```
if (userResponse == 'n' || 'N')
```

Try this instead:

```
if (userResponse == 'n' || userResponse =='N')
```

Comment: Maybe explain why the first conditional is always entered into? ('N' is converted to bool and since that's greater than 0 (ASCII value), the whole conditional becomes true)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define each logical operation individually in a condition check. You will have to compare `userResponse` with `n` and `N` separately.

```
if (userResponse == 'y' || userResponse == 'Y')
{
    cout << "How many orders of " << nameOfDish[i] << " would you like?\n";
    cin >> quantityOfDish[i];
    if (quantityOfDish[i] == 0) {
        cout << "I suppose you're entitled to change your mind.\n";
    }
    else if (quantityOfDish[i] < 0) {
        cout << "Your generosity is appreciated but I must decline!\n";
        quantityOfDish[i] = 0;
    }

    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I worked in C++, but I'm fairly sure I know what's going on.

The `||` operator does not work on a single conditional, there must be two complete conditionals, one on each side.  Try replacing your if statement with this line:

`if (userResponse == 'y' || userResponse == 'Y')`

Comment: Research your favorite C++ reference about operator precedence.  Consider the operator `||` as a function requiring two parameters.  The syntax is valid as long as the compiler can find a way to convert the arguments to `bool`.  There is also *sort-circuiting* that applies too.

Comment: I see, the original author did not say it was throwing an error as it might be from the way I described the situation, but rather the char 'Y' is being evaluated as True.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are used to SQL? You need to repeat the userResponse

```
if userResponse == 'n' || userResponse == 'N'
```

Otherwise you are actually testing

```
if userResponse is 'n' or  the char'N' exists
```

Comment: Nitpick:  A single letter is not a string.  A string literal is usually declared using double quotes; a character letter is between single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The error in this code is, as others have pointed out, the `if` statement. However, I feel this may need some clarification. Every C++ expression returns a value. For example.

```
userResponse == 'y'
```

returns the value `1` if `userResponse` is `'y'` and `0` if it is anything else. The operator `||` returns `1` if either the left or the right expression is non-zero.

Finally, the `if` statement checks to see whether or not the expression is zero or non-zero. So,

```
if (5)
  cout << "X";
else
  cout << "Y";
```

will print `X` and

```
if (0)
  cout << "A";
else
  cout << "B";
```

will print `B`.

Now, we can begin to understand why your code compiled successfully, but didn't do what you wanted it to.

```
if (userResponse == 'y' || 'Y')
```

In this example, the `||` operator will always return `1` because the expression on the right, `'Y'`, will always be non-zero (specifically, it will be `89`, since C++ characters are just aliases for their ASCII corresponding number). And of course,

```
if (userResponse == 'y' || userResponse == 'Y')
```

work as intended. But there is a much better solution and that would be the `switch` statement, whose purpose is to handle situations like this. Here it is in action:

```
switch (userResponse) {
  case 'y':
  case 'Y':
    //The user answered yes, handle that situation here.
    break;
  case 'n':
  case 'N':
    //The user answered no, handle that situation here.
    break;
  default:
    // The user did not enter a valid answer, 
    // handle that situation here.
    break;
}
```